# Responsive form html css

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form like this:

[image: large screen]

It looks normal until I open it on mobile screen:

[image: small screen]

HTML structure:

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="frmreport">
                  Booking Date :
                  <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; display:inline">
                      <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
                  </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <input type="hidden" name="input_date_from" id="input_date_from" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="input_date_to" id="input_date_to" value="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:5px 12px;margin-bottom:3px;" onclick="print_report('html');">
                      <i class="fi flaticon-copy"></i> View
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:5px 12px;margin-bottom:3px;" onclick="print_report('pdf');">
                      <i class="fi flaticon-download"></i> PDF
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:5px 12px;margin-bottom:3px;" onclick="print_report('csv');">
                      <i class="fi flaticon-download"></i> CSV
                  </button>
              </form>
```

I have tried to add `col-sm-6` but the CSV button break to a new line below View and PDF button. What should I add?

Comment: Why not use the Bootstap form framework to keep everything aligned on mobiles? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: @Lee, yes I agree, Mai you should prefer using Bootstrap. All you gotta do is include class name. It makes work simpler and easier. You can know about it here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code you had in the style="" attribute must be moved into a 
`<style></style>` tag or a css file, just copy this code in there

**CSS**

```
#reportrange{
background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; display:inline
}

#button{
padding:5px 12px;margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

**HTML** (i just added id's to the buttons just copy this in there)

```
<button type="button" id="button"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="print_report('html');">
<button type="button" id="button"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="print_report('html');">
<button type="button" id="button"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="print_report('html');">
```

Then use this in the CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
#button{
/* add all of your mobile styles in here    */
}
}
```

So in there you could change the padding and to see the result you could either view it on your phone or by resizing your browser

Comment: I know this has been marked as accepted, and if it's working that's great, but it would make much more sense, and would be a lot easier to use the standard bootstrap configurations for laying out forms.

Comment: @Lee that is completely true I use bootstrap myself as well all the time but I just thought to give him a raw css + html answer